# How do I change set display.fullscreen minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I change the display? I was told to do this:
{{
Display.setFullscreen(fullscreen);
Display.setResizable(false);
Display.setResizable(true);
}}
Here's the thing. The commenter never told us the file directory! I don't know what file to change making the advice useless.

Comment: This question makes very little sense.

Answer (score 0):

Press F11 ?

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Controls#Configurable_controls

Toggles full-screen mode.

When using some Apple keyboards, F11 must be pressed while holding fn and ⌥option to enter fullscreen. Using F11 alone toggles Exposé, and pressing F11 while holding fn will turn the volume down or vice versa, depending on system preferences.

Some people are experiencing a bug while exiting from full-screen mode that causes an inescapable black screen. When that's the case, use ALT+TAB to switch out of Minecraft and switch it back to windowed mode.

On Linux, mouse input is often buggy while in full-screen mode. After entering full-screen mode on Linux, the mouse will typically restrict the player to a single 360-degree rotation. This can be fixed by hitting ESC to release the mouse then hitting ESC again to regrab it.

Also, note that this may not respect multiple monitors and Minecraft may occupy all screens instead of the one it is active on.